# Reading a text file in verilog HDL

Tags: verilog

I can't read a text file in verilog which contains the following:

> b05_test.dut.n509 0

I'm blocked at the fgets instruction `scan_faults = $fgets(file_faults , string , data);`  because it doesn't work and i tried with fsancf without any positive results.

Any help please?

---

Full Code:

```
integer file_faults;
integer scan_faults;
wire data;

initial begin
  file_faults = $fopen("faults.txt", "r");
  if (file_faults == 0) begin
    $display("data_file handle was NULL");
    $finish;
  end
end

always @(* ) begin
  if (!$feof(file_faults)) begin
    scan_faults = $fgets(file_faults , data);
  end
  else begin
    $finish;
    $fclose(file_faults);
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i don't see any difference in simulation i can't understand why.Actually i'm trying to inject a fault to a circuit but it doesn't work.Can you help me on this please?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain what I'm trying to do,I have an electronic circuit and I want to estimate its behaviour when there is an error.The probleme is how to inject a single fault (serial fault injection) using verilog and modelsim,so i got the idea of writing a fault list and read it in my testbench.

Comment: I have used $fscanf and it works fine on modelsim. I had used it to test my branch predictor. `$fscanf(data_file, "B%d,%s\n", branch_index_full,captured_data);` In order to help you out, you would need to give us a working example of your code.

Comment: `integer               file_faults;  
integer               scan_faults;
wire data;

initial 
begin
file_faults = $fopen("faults.txt", "r");
if (file_faults == 0) begin  
$display("data_file handle was NULL");
$finish;
    end
end
always @(* )
begin

   if (!$feof(file_faults)) 
   begin

scan_faults = $fgets(file_faults , data); 

  end

   else
   begin

   $finish;
   $fclose(file_faults);
end 
end
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 21.3.4.2 *Reading a line at a time*:

> One line can be read from a file using **`$fgets`**. For example:
>
> ```
> integer code;
> code = $fgets ( str, fd );
> ```
>
> reads characters from the file specified by `fd` into the variable `str` until `str` is filled, or a newline character is read and transferred to `str`, or an `EOF` condition is encountered. If `str` is not an integral number of bytes in length, the most significant partial byte is not used in order to determine the size.
>   If an error occurs reading from the file, then `code` is set to zero. Otherwise, the number of characters read is returned in `code`. Applications can call `$ferror` to determine the cause of the most recent error (see 21.3.7).

Therefore, your code needs to look something like this:

```
integer file_faults;
integer scan_faults;
reg [7:0] data; // needs to be an "integral number of bytes in length"

initial begin
  file_faults = $fopen("faults.txt", "r");
  if (file_faults == 0) begin
    $display("data_file handle was NULL");
    $finish;
  end
  while (!$feof(file_faults)) begin
    scan_faults = $fgets(data, file_faults); // arg order was wrong in original
    $display("scan_faults: %0d  data: %s", scan_faults, data);
  end
  $fclose(file_faults); // Close file before finish
  $finish;
end
```

If you want to out variable(s) from a when it incounters a specific format, then look into `$fscanf`. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 21.3.4.3 *Reading formatted data*